# ticks disappearing for diverging (out of range) plots

Tags: pgfplots

my xticks disappear for some plots even though I explicitly ask for them. Here is my MWE. The function goes to -infinity at the right border of the interval.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[domain=0:1]
        \begin{semilogyaxis}[xtick={0,0.5,1}]
            \addplot[mark=none,samples=300] {x - 1/(4 - 4*x) + 5/4};
        \end{semilogyaxis}  
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

How do I get them back? A general idea how to deal with the plotting of divergent functions would be great.

Comment: You'll have to set `xmax=1` to make sure that that point is included in your range. The `domain` keyword only sets the computational range for the `\addplot` command, but not the visible range of the axis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make sure that all the ticks that you specify using `xtick` are actually visible, you will have to adjust the axis limits using `xmin` and `xmax`, making sure that the tick range is completely covered. In your case, simply saying `xmax=1` does the trick.

The `domain` keyword only sets the computational range, not the visible one. If you use, say, `domain=0:100`, but `xmin=0, xmax=1`, the functions given in `\addplot` commands will be evaluated everywhere between 0 and 100, even though the range from 1 to 99 will not be plotted. Similarly, if you set `domain=0:1, xmin=0, xmax=100`, the function will only be evaluated (and plotted) between 0 and 1, but the axis will range from 0 to 100, so most of the plot range will be empty.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[domain=0:1]
        \begin{semilogyaxis}[xtick={0,0.5,1}, xmax=1]
            \addplot[mark=none,samples=300] {x - 1/(4 - 4*x) + 5/4};
        \end{semilogyaxis}  
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```